# How to get back column value if df.ColumnName, where Columnname is comes from user in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

My code is below in Pyspark:

```
Product = results.where(results.ColumnName == ProductName )
Product.show()
```

Where i want ColumnName should come from User like:

```
ColumnName = input("enter column name")
```

but I get the error as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-3e0600c86491> in <module>()
----> 1 Prediction_Product_Wise = results.where(results.ColumnName == ProductName ).select( 
ColumnName,'probability','prediction').orderBy("probability",ascending=False)
  2 Prediction_Product_Wise.show()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
 1399         if name not in self.columns:
 1400             raise AttributeError(
 -> 1401                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
 1402         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
 1403         return Column(jc)

 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ColumnName'
```

Basically I wanted to check whether Product column has that value in it or not.
For example

```
Product
apple
ball
cat
```

and the data frame is df then `df.Product == apple` should return `True` value.
And I want to give user that at place of Product column he/she can choose any column name according to preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ColumnName` is a string, you can do this.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

Product = results.where(col(ColumnName) === ProductName)
Product.show()
```

Comment: Worked like champ!

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a function like this to do your task. This will return False for columns which are not there in the dataframe.

```
def is_value(df, column_name: str, value):
    if column_name in df.columns:
        return bool(df.where(df[column_name] == value).first())
    return False
```